# Dart - Suppress printing stack trace to console on Future catchError

Tags: dart

Is it possible to not print a stack trace to console when an error is caught in a Future?  My goal is to catch the error and add information to the stack trace before it is printed.  Here's a simple code example.

```
_runCommand().then((_) {
    return _finish();
}).catchError((e, s) {
    _catchCriticalError(e, s);
});
```

When `catchError` is called, the stack trace has already been printed to console.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3875bd903b75a2babbd25260a07050ce

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You're right.  Your example worked, but the exception was occurring inside the `then`.  I may need to implement `onError` inside of `then`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you modify my example so that your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the example, and I misspoke in my previous comment regarding the `then`.  So if I throw an error in the `_runCommand` function before it returns, it is not being caught by `catchError`.  The actual code I'm working with is much more complicated than this with nested functions, and I solved the problem by moving error catching further down into the lower functions.